# Installing Python-GDAL with OSGEO?

Tags: python, gdal, installation, osgeo, osgeo4w

I have been trying to install python gdal with OSGEO for some time now with no success. I have removed. I have tried with "Express and Advance" as suggested by OSGEO4W site.

The error is always "No module named 'osgeo' or gdal", the command line also does not recognise an internal program.

Comment: If it is in Windows try to run it in Osgeo shell rather than normal command prompt

Comment: I have tried but still getting the same message

Comment: Check whether the path is correct? echo %PATH% command list all paths in command prompt. Check python path also ?

Comment: What python version do you have?

Comment: The echo %PATH% also includes paths for previously installed python versions, I removed python 3.4 then installed 2.7

Answer (score 3):

Summerizing the 4 steps from the answer of Khoa:

- go to [this site](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php) to download appropriate windows binaries (once you've clicked on the appropriate version of GDAL bianaries, select GDAL core to download the main fucntionnalities).
- install GDAL with default (or not ?) settings
- return to the page where you got GDAL core and download GDAL python bindings to work with your python version
- install python bbindings

Answer (score 3):

For ubuntu, run the following:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
pip install GDAL
```

Source: https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html

Also potentially of interest, the GDAL binaries https://gdal.org/download.html

Comment: Did not work for me. Got an error: 
`error: legacy-install-failure`

Answer (score 3):

For ubuntu:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev gdal-bin

# Sanity, check the version. For ubuntu 18.04, it's probably 2.4.2
ogrinfo --version

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

sudo apt install python3.8-dev. <-- NOTE the python version should match yours
pip3 install GDAL==$(ogrinfo --version | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d',' -f1)


# If the above doesn't work, input the version manually from ogrinfo
# pip3 install GDAL==2.4.2 (Or any other version received from ogrinfo)
```

Answer (score 2):

On MacOSX:

1. Conda installation: (Easy mode)

From https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal

Assuming you have conda installed,
`conda install -c conda-forge gdal`
That's it you're done, conda installs the underlying gdal binaries for you.

2. Using brew/pip

```
brew install gdal # This installs the underlying binaries

pip install gdal  #(inside your venvs or whatever for python bindings)
```

You may get clang errors during the pip install, in which case you probably don't have the latest xcode build tools.

There is a longwided reason for why this occurs, but tl;dr go and download the latest version of the command line tools for xcode https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

Answer (score 1):

Follow the 4-step instruction on this site:
https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows

I found this site after hours of failing in installing osgeo.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. Can you summarize the 4 steps on your link. In case the link changes in the future, there is some record of what the user must to if they encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

1

For ubuntu: 20.04 LTS

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev gdal-bin
```

####Sanity, check the version. For ubuntu 18.04, it's probably 2.4.2
ogrinfo --version

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
```

sudo apt install python3.8-dev. <-- NOTE the python version should match yours
pip3 install GDAL==3.3.2

###### NOTE THAT IF THE pip3 install GDAL=3.3.2 DOES NOT WORK FOR ANACONDA(FOR ME WHEELS WERE CREATING ISSUE) THEN RUN THE BELOW:

`conda install -c conda-forge gdal==3.3.2` (Or any other version received from ogrinfo)